# attr_accessible <-> :as => :admin <-> db:seed <->

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I am sort of in a catch22 situation.

1. If have to protect the 'role' attribute for a user from mass assignment problems I have to use attr_accessible and exclude it.
2. But then if I have to allow an admin to set it then I have to add :as => :admin using assign_attributes.
3. But then db:seed won't work if I have to setup some default roles.

Is there a way to accomplish all three needs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways around mass assignment but I'm not really a fan of them.

For example:

```
role = Role.new
role.assign_attributes({...}, :without_protection => true)
role.save
```

I prefer to use a gem I wrote called [sudo_attributes](https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes) that gives you "sudo" privileges:

```
Role.sudo_create(...)
```

The API is identical to ActiveRecord's for creating and instantiating models.

Comment: I installed sudo_attributes and now I can use attr_accessible in my models and used sudo_create! im my controllers & seeds.rb and it all works great. I am able to meet all 3 requirements in my original question. When I have some free time I would love to peek inside your gem to see how you are doing it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, feel free to upvote my answer :). The gem is essentially a wrapper for the built-in Rails methods and doesn't require any real magic. I found myself in the same situation as you a lot so I wrote it. https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes/blob/master/lib/sudo_attributes.rb#L94

Comment: Very interesting — struggling with this today, my controller update method is made exceedingly ugly attempting to use attr_accessible roles functionality ... will definitely check out your gem, but also curious what the core team expects us to do – no samples cover update case.

Comment: @MBHNYC the core team is actually removing all of this from Rails 4 in favor of enforcing security in the controller where params come in.

Comment: Indeed - looking forward to seeing some best practice examples